# Wrapping an Observable/Subscription

Tags: android, retrofit, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I have a login service handling nicely in my Activity using Retrofit with an Observable return type as:

```
mApiService.login(new LoginRequest("username", "password"))
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext(loginObjectResponse -> /* write to disk */ )
    .flatmap(loginObjectResponse -> /* manipulate */)
    .subscribe(loginObjectResponse -> /* update UI */, e -> /* update UI */);
```

What I'd like to do is pull out the logic in doOnNext and flatmap into a separate class, and ultimately simplify in the Activity down to:

```
mManager.login("username", "password")
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(booleanResult -> /* update UI */, e -> /* update UI */);
```

And handle the API service call in my manager class.

I'm looking for advice on the best way to achieve this. I'd obviously like my manager class to return an Observable, but can I keep using the Retrofit Observable (and wrap the Subscription?) or am I better off just making it a little more synchronous and just create and return a simple Observable?

**UPDATE**

I came across some samples that made me think about approaching this differently by just building the operation chain in my manager class and letting it all execute upon subscription in my Activity. My manager method now uses defer and resembles:

```
public Observable login(String username, String password) {
    return Observable.defer(() ->
        mApiService.login(new LoginRequest(username, password))
            .doOnNext(loginResponse -> /* write to disk */ )
            .flatMap(loginResponse -> return Observable.just(loginResponse); )
        );
}
```

With my Activity subscribing as shown above.

Hoping for insight whether I'm in the ballpark, or any advice on how to better handle this use case.  Thanks!

**UPDATE2**

So the defer served no purpose here. Login method has boiled down to:

```
public Observable login(String username, String password) {
    return mApiService.login(new LoginRequest(username, password))
        .doOnNext(loginResponse -> /* write to disk */ )
        .flatMap(loginResponse -> return Observable.just(loginResponse); )
    );
}
```

Still would appreciate any comments/improvements to this approach. Most examples I've come across just do everything where their subscription takes place.

Comment: Defering here doesnt give you much - execution wont start until you subscribe anyway, so you can return login(...).doOnNext().flatMap() directly

Comment: Ah, good call. I assumed defer got it working for me earlier, but I think it was in combination with an emulator restart.

That aside, is there anything you'd suggest changing here?  I haven't really seen many examples of Observables getting refactored out into other methods.

Comment: You might also look at compose method and Transformer class and use it to replace observeOn(Schedulers.io()) and
    subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) since they are usually used altogheter. Also note that your login method returns Observable without generic type specified

Comment: Ah, very cool.  Thanks for the info.